# How do I put a username from session in folder directory in PHP?

Tags: php, session, directory

So this is what I am trying to do.
Make a folder in the *uploads/* folder with the username of the user that is currently logged in. Example: *uploads/bob*

```
if (!file_exists('uploads/username')) {
    mkdir('uploads/username'), 0777, true);
}
```

I have the username stored in `$_SESSION['Username']`

Comment: sidenote: 777 isn't safe, use 755.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
if (!file_exists('uploads/'.$_SESSION['Username'])) {
    mkdir('uploads/'.$_SESSION['Username']), 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir('uploads/' . $_SESSION['Username']), 0777, true);
```

The above code should work

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a start in the right direction...

```
$username = $_SESSION['Username'];
if (!file_exists("uploads/$username")) {
    mkdir("uploads/$username"), 0777, true);
}
```